# Google Scripts - run one function after another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a Google Script which ties to a Google Sheet and makes several alterations on edit. On *any* change, the script should re-sort the rows by a particular column. On change in a particular column, the script should create a date value in an adjacent column of that row (ie, if you edit C2, it should create a date in D2 matching the date of editing).

I have all of the basic functionality for each function working fine, and they are working perfectly on their own. The issue is ordering/timing.

I edit C2, so it creates a date in D2. But, apparently, *before* it does so, it re-sorts the rows, so that the row that I edited is now in a new location, and the date appears in the wrong row. (I think it might be more accurate to say that it sorts the rows *while* it's processing the function to add a date).

The end result is that the date cell is filled on the correct row, numerically (ie, D2), but the contents of row 2 have by that point moved to another location, so it's in the wrong row content-wise.

Here are my functions:

```
function reSort() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C1000");

 // Sorts descending by column B
 range.sort({column: 3, ascending: true });
}

function saveDate (event) {
  var ss = event.source; 
  var range = event.range;
  var a1 = range.getA1Notation();
  var col = a1[0];
  var row = a1.slice(1);

  // If status has just been modified
  if (col === 'C' && a1.length >= 1) {
    var dateCell = ss.getRange('D'.concat(row)).getCell(1,1);

    // Empty date if status is null
    if (event.value === '') {
      dateCell.setValue('');
    // Otherwise, add date
    } else {
      var date = new Date();
      dateCell.setValue([date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()].join('/'))
    }
  }
}

function saveDateAndResort(event) {
  saveDate(event);
  reSort();
}
```

It seems that the solution would be to run one function and then the other (specifically, save the date, and then resort). That's what I try to do in `saveDateAndResort`, which is the function which is triggered. But the same asynchronous behavior still seems to occur. I'd love to run one and *then* the other, only once the first has completed, but when I tried `setTimeout` it didn't work (specifically, it seems to ignore the content inside the timeout function call).

Am I missing something basic or doing something wrong? This seems to behave strangely.

Comment: How are you tying your functions to the change (edit) event? I've always created a function with the reserved name `onEdit`. What I'm wondering is if your code is being called recursively because of the changes (edits) you're making to the sheet when you sort. If that's the case, then you can set an `inProcess` flag that you can use to disable further processing while your functions are running. A timer isn't a good idea for this situation.

Comment: In your situation, after you modify cell "C2" and the date is put to "D2", when the rows are sorted, the row number of "D2" corresponding to "C2" is different. If my understanding is correct and you use the script, ``A2:C1000`` of ``sheet.getRange("A2:C1000")`` is required to be modified to ``A2:D1000`` (or ``A2:E1000``, ``A2:F1000``,,?) by including the column "D". By this, when the rows are sorted, the values of columns from "A" to "D" are moved, simultaneously. By the way, the comment in your script says ``Sorts descending by column B``. But in your script, it's ascending by column "C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is indeed asynchronous, You should use the latter function inside the former. But, That won't be a issue.  Issue is changes made to spreadsheet are cached. You should use [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) to flush the cache before other calls are made.

#### Snippets:

```
function saveDateAndResort(event) {
  saveDate(event);
}
function saveDate(event){
  //code to save date here
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//flush cache 
  reSort();
}
```