# Google Apps Script - How to execute functions one after another?

Tags: google-apps-script, sequential

**1) My Goal**

- I'm trying to write a Google Apps Script that runs 3 functions step by step with a small pause after each step
- Basically: 1) Fill cells with specific content 2) Send content from cells to email address 3) delete content from cells

**2) My Challenge**

- Google Apps Script is running all functions simultanioulsy

**3) What have I tried?**

- SpreadsheetApp.flush(); as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824578/google-scripts-run-one-function-after-another) - but did not work out

**4) My Code**

```
function pastecontent() {

  // Fetch spreadsheet 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // copy paste from first row to all others
  var source = sheet.getRange("D6:F6");
  source.copyTo (sheet.getRange("D7:F22"));  
   
}

function sendEmails() {

   // pause for X seconds  
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
 
  // Fetch spreadsheet 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       
  // get the range and values in one step
  var values = sheet.getRange("D7:F22").getValues();
  
  // Send Mail
  var message = values + " https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[....]"; 
  var emailAddress = "XYZ@gmail.com"; 
  var subject = "Test Mail";
  if (cell != "") {
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}

function clearcontent() {

  // pause for X seconds  
  Utilities.sleep(8000);

  // Fetch spreadsheet 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // clear cells
  sheet.getRange("D7:F22").clearContent();
   
}
```

Thanks for your support
Joe

Comment: you don't seem to have a "master" function that runs all the 3 other functions. Are you sure you ran them all together? Also `does not` work is not descriptive enough. Provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main function to call all functions:

```
function main() {
  pastecontent();
  sendEmails();
  clearcontent();
}
```

Sample Log:

[image: sample output]

I haven't changed anything in your code aside from the email and it went smoothly.

Just make sure to have a main function that calls them one by one.

Aside from that, I'm not seeing any issues with your code

Nitpick: The `cell` variable wasn't defined before sending the email. Declaration wasn't included in the code provided so I declared it in mine. You might want to add that if you don't have it in yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can organize your code like this

```
function mainFunction(){
  pastecontent();
  Utilities.sleep(200);// pause in the loop for 200 milliseconds
  sendEmails();
  Utilities.sleep(200);/
  clearcontent();
}
```